# Application.Run() leads to application hanging

Tags: c#, runtime-error, exit

When I start application without specific form e.g.

```
Application.Run();
```

And then I create form, after user closes it, the process just hangs.

This happens outside of Visual Studio.

I tried to put `Application.Exit()` and/or `Application.ExitThread()` in form's `Form_Closing` event, but it still hangs.

Edit: Using custom ApplicationContext unfortunately doesn't work.

FYI, I'm not using any threads nor BackgroundWorkers.

Comment: @BestArmy: I think I did (according to my comment below), but I don't remember how. It's been more than 4 years ago. In past year I've worked only on one small WinForms application, otherwise it's been only  WPF/XAML for me.

Comment: Tod bad you didn't post the answer here. You sure you cant remember?

Comment: Yeah, that's too bad, I didn't. I am sorry, but I really don't remember, what I did back then. I don't even remember, what application it was, otherwise I could try looking up its source code. Unfortunately, you have to figure it out on your own (I believe you've tried answers here).

Answer (score 2):

Use Tools + Attach to Process to attach the debugger to the hung process.  Debug + Break All.  Debug + Windows + Threads, double-click the Main thread and look at its call stack to see what it is doing.  Post the stack trace in your question if that doesn't help.

Comment: It's hung at Application.Run() line.

Comment: :) Really, there's just External code and the line in Program.cs (Application.Run()). Trust me, I've done some work with Call stack.

Comment: Okay, then you'll be comfortable with turning unmanaged debugging on.  Setup the Microsoft Symbol Server.  Project + Properties, Debug, tick "Unmanaged".  The call stack will now show you what unmanaged code is running.

Comment: Care to share what you did for the benefit of others?

Comment: @mnn Care to share what you did to figure it out? (not sure if the other comment notified you)

Comment: @sirdank I'm truly sorry, but I have no idea, what the root issue was. The first comment did notify me, I just didn't have time to respond at the time (I didn't remember then remember either). I did respond to a comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503812/application-run-leads-to-application-hanging/4503874?noredirect=1#comment48367651_4503812.

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN for the parameterless Application.Run():

> Most Windows Forms developers will not
>   need to use this version of the
>   method. You should use the Run(Form)
>   overload to start an application with
>   a main form, so that the application
>   terminates when the main form is
>   closed. For all other situations, use
>   the Run(ApplicationContext) overload,
>   which supports supplying an
>   ApplicationContext object for better
>   control over the lifetime of the
>   application.

So, short answer, try specifying an ApplicationContext object, or just Run() the form you are creating and showing. Maybe a more concrete example of why you're trying to open the message loop without tying it to a form would help. Are you opening several forms? Is this an introductory form like a splash screen or a login?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the overload of `Application.Run(new MyForm()`) instead, though Application.Exit() should be working for you as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx).