# C# hang and stuck after Application.Run() at for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, for-loop, webbrowser-control

Im building a program that surf to several websites and do something.

After surfing to like 5 urls successfully, the program hangs after the Application.Run() line. 
The program doesn't even enter the Handler function and just stuck. the CPU usage is 0 at this point.

I tried closing the threads in any possible way.
What i'm doing wrong?

I'm doing it like that:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++) 
    {
        var th = new Thread(() = > 
        {
            var weBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            weBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
            weBrowser.DocumentCompleted += Handler;
            weBrowser.Navigate(urls[i]);
            Application.Run();
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
        th.Join();
    }
}
```

And my Handle function is:

```
private static void Handler(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    WebBrowser weBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
    var htmlDocument = weBrowser.Document;

    /*do something*/

    Application.Exit();
    Application.ExitThread();

    weBrowser.Dispose();
    weBrowser.Stop();

    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
}
```

My problem is very similar to this one:
[Application.Run() leads to application hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503812/application-run-leads-to-application-hanging)

There is no answer in this question either.

Thanks!

Comment: My approach to this, using `Task` API and `async`/`await`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303

Comment: What are you actually trying to DO?  I haven't used WebBrowser before, but a quick glance over the docs suggests that it's basically a full-featured rendering and control engine, and if you don't *need* that much power, you shouldn't be using it.  If all you're trying to do is grab source text from a list of pages, the answer can be as simple as throwing `WebRequest` into a `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach` loop...

Answer (score 9):

I think you are doing several mistakes:

- you are joining inside the for look
- you are calling `Application.Exit()` in each handler call

You should move the joining outside the for loop and do not call `Application.Exit`.

The following sample seems to work well:

```
static class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
     var urls = new List<string>() { 
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "http://stackoverflow.com"};

     var threads = new Thread[urls.Count];

     for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
     {
        threads[i] = new Thread((url) =>
        {
           var weBrowser = new WebBrowser();
           weBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
           weBrowser.DocumentCompleted += Handler;
           weBrowser.Navigate(url as string);
           Application.Run();
        });
        threads[i].SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        threads[i].Start(urls[i]);
     }

     foreach (var t in threads)
        t.Join();

     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new Form1());
  }

  private static void Handler(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
     WebBrowser weBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;

     var htmlDocument = weBrowser.Document;

     /*do something*/

     Application.ExitThread();

     weBrowser.Dispose();
     weBrowser.Stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. The program runs now on more sites than before, but after 25-30 sites its stop like before. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Im pulling data
foreach (HtmlElement el in htmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
            {....}

But it doesn't realy metter. Mayb there is max thread limit?

Comment: No, I mean, why are you doing this in `Main`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im writing a console application that pull data from some urls..
So it is starting in Main function.

Comment: I dont have .net 4.5, But  I think it can work. 
Still, I'm very intrested in why the program just STUCK at Application.Run(), the CPU usage goes to 0 and there is no progress. It's very wierd. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `urls[i]` in your original snippets is wrong. Search C# documentation for **closures**. You will need to make a local copy before using it.

Furthermore, you should swap `weBrowser.Dispose()` and `weBrowser.Stop()`. You can't stop the disposed browser anymore (if `Stop` is necessary at all).

Finally, don't abort the thread - it will finish itself.

Comment: I tried everything to close the thread-with or without weBrowser.* and it didnt work. If I dont abort the thread it doesnt close it self(program wait at join). You know another ways to close threads?

Comment: Set a breakpoint after Application.Run() - you will see that it is triggered after Application.ExitThread is executed. If you abort the thread, weBrowser.Dispose is not called.

Comment: The problem is that the program hangs at Application.Run() after few threads created. the threads are closing, but new arn't created at some point.

Comment: Please test the breakpoint with only one thread. You should see how the thread is finished after that. Also, confirm that weBrowser.Dispose is executed. Finally, post a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem. BTW, what dou you mean by "the program hangs at Application.Run" - Application.Run is always blocking...

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into the maximum number of concurrent connections for the WebBrowser. By explicitly setting this to a higher number, you can have additional streams reading through the browser at once.

```
// Example Usage:
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
```

Keep in mind that there is a performance hit by increasing this number above the default (I think it is 4) as you will have much more network traffic that needs processed.

See the MSDN article for [ConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what would you like to achieve with Application.Run inside for loop.

Why are you using WebBrowser component? If you are just parsing web page it is better to use

```
string urlAddress = "http://stackoverflow.com"; 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    StreamReader reader= null;
    if (response.CharacterSet == null)
        reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    else
        reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
    string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

or

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

For parsing html look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or something similar.

If this is console application you don't need to call Application.Run(), otherwise you should consider showing splash screen with progress to give user some feedback.